# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-u^2+v^2}dudv$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

For (i) I did it by turning the integrand into infinite series, but  what is the method by applying binomial theorem?

For (iii) I'm unsure as to a good "trigonometric substitution".

Comment: Please see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Basel_Problem/Proof_1

Comment: For the first question, the binomial expansion of a similar function $$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + \frac{1}{2}\cdot (1)(2)x^2+\cdots
$$

or [negative binomial expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html)